# How to Mock and test using an RxJS subject?

Tags: rxjs5

I have some functions that accept an RxJS subject (backed to a socket) that I want to test. I'd like to mock the subject in a very request reply fashion. Since I'm unsure of a clean Rx way to do this, I'm tempted to use an EventEmitter to form my fake socket.

Generally, I want to:

- check that the message received on my "socket" matches expectations
- respond to that message on the same subject: `observer.next(resp)`

I do need to be able to use data from the message to form the response as well.

---

The code being tested is

```
export function acquireKernelInfo(sock) {
  // set up our JSON payload
  const message = createMessage('kernel_info_request');

  const obs = shell
    .childOf(message)
    .ofMessageType('kernel_info_reply')
    .first()
    .pluck('content', 'language_info')
    .map(setLanguageInfo)
    .publishReplay(1)
    .refCount();

  sock.next(message);
  return obs;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manually create two subjects and "glue them together" as one Subject with `Subject.create`:

```js
const sent = new Rx.Subject();
const received = new Rx.Subject();

const mockWebSocketSubject = Subject.create(sent, received)

const s1 = sent.subscribe(
  (msg) => sentMsgs.push({ next: msg }),
  (err) => sentMsgs.push({ error: err }),
  () => sendMsgs.push({ complete: true })
);

const s2 = recieved.subscribe(
  (msg) => sentMsgs.push({ next: msg }),
  (err) => sentMsgs.push({ error: err }),
  () => sendMsgs.push({ complete: true })
);


// to send a message
// (presumably whatever system you're injecting this into is doing the sending)
sent.next('weee');

// to mock a received message
received.next('blarg');

s1.unsubscribe();
s2.unsubscribe();
```

That said, it's really a matter of what you're testing, how it's structured, and what the API is.

Ideally you'd be able to run your whole test synchronously. If you can't for some Rx-related reason, you should look into the `TestScheduler`, which has facilities to run tests in virtualized time.